# Driver for a CW laser diode

Tags: driver, led-driver, laser-diode, laser-driver

I have a 20mW CW laser diode that I want to control with a microcontroller.

I found that it has to be powered by a constant current circuit so that the power of the laser never changes.

I have been looking for an suitable circuit but haven't found anything good for me yet. I found the commonly used LM317 circuit but it isn't very efficient and I need a solution for mass production. Does anybody know an suitable and efficient circuit and maybe even a suitable IC?

[edit]
I added a datasheet of the laser diode

[image]

Comment: is it really important that the power never changes? or is it okay if it changes a bit?

Comment: Part recommendations are off topic.  What circuit you need depends on what you need to do.  Have you seen [this Analog Devices application note?](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an90f.pdf)  It has some good information about constant current sources for laser diodes.  [This Analog Device IC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/obsolete-data-sheets/AD9661A.pdf) is for controlling laser diodes that have a feedback output.  Have a look at those two documents, then think about your requirements.

Comment: "*never changes*" is an impossible spec. If this is medical you should have a specification for allowable deviation.

Comment: The LM317 is meant for regulating a constant voltage, not current.  Can you edit the question to include a link to the laser diode datasheet?  Does the LD include a photo diode for feedback? (If so, it would have 3 pins.)

Comment: "As little as possible" means spending $100's on precision resistors, precision IC's, active cooling, etc. A spec like "+/- 5%" or "+/- 1%" would probably get you a solution in the $1 to $10 range.

Comment: People will harp on non-engineering statements like _"so that the power of the laser never changes"_ and _"can change a bit, but as less as possible"_ until you give hard values for limits. If your question is not about how to achieve high accuracy, I would recommend you remove all mentions of accuracy.